# How to pick 30 questions from 500 possible questions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, web

I am developing my first web app with the help from JQuery Mobile framework. 
The thing is a exam simulator(multiple choice) in which, after a main menu, the app sequentially shows to the user the questions and the user pick between three posible answers. The user have to answer 30 questions, picked randomly from, lets say, 500 possible questions. And at the end i display the results (% of questions answered right).

The problem is that i don't have idea, conceptually i guess,how to do the picking randomly 30 questions part (i guess that every question will be a jquery mobile page?) from a repository (?????) of 500 possible questions.

Any help or orientation will be much appreciated.

Comment: What about an array? Store your question in array and random some index to fetch the question.

Comment: One idea would be to use an sqlite DB for your repository. You can get random questions via the simple query `SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 30`.

Comment: Adding to @Dvir , try creating a class object and index them. Then just iterate through each of the questions (in your new object array) using rand() to get the proper index as you cycle through.

Answer (score 1):

From an algorithmic point of view, selecting `n` random questions from `x` total can be done by looping over the `x` questions and selecting each one with a probability equal to `the number of questions you still need to pick` / `the number of questions remaining to be picked from`.

Here is a quick demo:

```
var a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var select = (n) => {
    return a.reduce((memo, val, index) => {
        var p = (n-memo.length); // How many remaining to choose.
        var q = a.length-index; // How many remaining to choose from.
        if (Math.random() < p/q){
            memo.push(val);
        }
        return memo;
    }, []);
};

console.log(select(3));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1aedhan8/